# Locate duplicate information between two spreadsheets

Tags: excel

I run an open order report for a warehouse team every two days, and then go through the open orders; and email vendors to confirm their delivery date as pointed out by the report.

Naturally the reports are going to have some of the same information every other day, but there will be new orders, as well.

What I need to be able to do is figure out a way to tell the new spreadsheet to determine if any of the information in the new sheet was in the old sheet.

For example.

A, B, C, D, is Delivery Date, Part Number, Part Description, and Purchase Order Number - Respectively.

Information in spreadsheets in internal and confidential, otherwise I would post a photo of it, to help understand.

I want it to tell me if those items match between both spreadsheets, so that I don't suddenly end up asking twice about an order or have to go line by line to match up. Because that takes FOREVER.

Comment: Is the purchase order number unique or does it apply to multiple rows? Is there any unique identifier for a row of data? You can use lookup formulas to check if items exist in another file. A unique identifier would make this easier. Please update your post with a better data sample. Post a sample file with some dummy data but the same data structure. Use a file sharing service and post the link.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from editing your question to include several rows of redacted sample data to illustrate your problem. See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for equality across all items, you can do it easily with an array formula.  Here is an example that compares 4 columns (similar to you) for exact matches.  It multiples the combined result by `ROW` so that you can see where the last match occurs.  It is the last one because `MAX` is used.

Hopefully you can see how this would be extended to your case.  Note that this is an array formula (entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>) in cell `F2` copied down through the column.

Formula in cell `F2`

```
=MAX((A2=$H$2:$H$21)*(B2=$I$2:$I$21)*(C2=$J$2:$J$21)*(D2=$K$2:$K$21)*ROW($H$2:$H$21))
```

This formula works by building up a product of comparisons which is the same as an `AND` operation.  This will be a 1 if the conditions are all true.  That 1 is then multiplied by the `ROW` so that the match location is returned.

Picture with a couple matching rows colored and the ranges in color to see how the formula works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the purchase orders are unique day to day, you can use the match function in a column on the new orders page to see if the same PO is on the old PO's tab. If you get a #N/A the values are unique. Otherwise, Match will return the row number of the matching value.

If you need to match on multiple values (e.g. Date, PO, Part#) then use the concatenate formula to create a multi-part key.

```
=Concatenate(Text(DateCell, "YYYYMMDD"),"_", PO,"_", Part#)
```

Then put the same formula on both sheets and do the match on your new key column.

Comment: I almost posted this version of it.  The only downside is having matching formulas in two sheets which may make maintaining the spreadsheets harder.